# Search for function with specific signature call?

Tags: c++, function, debugging, signature, trace

Assume I have some C++ functions:

```
void A(int i) {
/* some code */
}

void A(string s) {
/* some code */
}

void A(string s, int i) {
/* some code */
}
```

Assume the first call makes 80% of the A() calls, the second makes 15% and the last makes 5%.

I want to static trace the calls. If I am interested in in the first kind of call, no problem, most of the string search results of "A(" will be of type 1, but if I ONLY want type 2 or type 3, I will have a lot of unneeded noise from type 1.

For type 3, regular expressions can help if I look for a following string that has exactly 2 comas between parenthesis `A(*,*,*)` (I don't actually know the programming syntax for RE)

But for type 2 this won't work.

Is there any technique I can use to find a function call by its signature?

Edit: What I mean by "trace" is understanding the current codebase by finding all the call points of the needed function.

Comment: _"I want to static trace the calls."_ What do you exactly mean _trace_? Are you using a logging framework, or do you want to set that as a breakpoint condition for the debugger?

Comment: You may be looking for [clang query or other parts of libtooling](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchers.html). The libtooling stuff is quite good for writing custom tools to search/query/manipulate the AST.

Comment: If this is your own code, there is a very simple pragmatic solution: Exclude declaration of `void A(string s)` and rebuild complete project. Afterwards, you will have a compiler error whenever function `A()` is called this way. This has, of course, certain limitations - compiler may choose another `A()` (from another namespace or by applying conversions to argument). - I mean this partly seriously: Whenever I cannot prevent to change certain basic behavior of our lib. functions I consider an "API break" to find all places which have to be re-visited/checked.

Comment: @Scheff _"I mean this partly seriously"_ Well, don't we have things like a [`deprecated`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/deprecated) attribute, in the current standard? That would solve your mentioned limitations IMO.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ So, instead of excluding it just mark it as `[[deprecated]]` and rebuild anything? Nice idea. I'm not sure whether VS2013 already supports it but one day we surely will switch... ;-)

Comment: @Scheff Unfortunately it doesn't: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c111417-features-in-vs-2015-rtm/

Comment: @Scheff Wait, who was mentioning VS2013 at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For type 3, regular expressions can help if I look for a following string that has exactly 2 comas between parenthesis A(*,*,*) (I don't actually know the programming syntax for RE)
>
> But for type 2 this won't work.
>
> Is there any technique I can use to find a function call by its signature?

Well besides you search your files using some regex (with e.g. Notepad++ file search, egrep or similar), and assuming that you're able to change the source code where these functions are declared / defined, you may use some compiler standard feature like the [`[[deprecated]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/deprecated) attribute:

```
   void A(int i) {
   /* some code */
   }

   [[deprecated]] void A(string s) {
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   /* some code */
   }

   [[deprecated]] void A(string s, int i) {
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   /* some code */
   }
```

This will show you warnings when these functions are used:

```
int main() {
    A(5);
    A("Hello");
    A("Hello",42);
}
```

> ```
> main.cpp:9:25: note: declared here
>      [[deprecated]] void A(string s) {
>                          ^
> main.cpp:20:18: warning: 'void A(std::__cxx11::string)' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
>          A("Hello");
>                   ^
> main.cpp:9:25: note: declared here
>      [[deprecated]] void A(string s) {
>                          ^
> main.cpp:21:21: warning: 'void A(std::__cxx11::string, int)' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
>          A("Hello",42);
>                      ^
> main.cpp:13:25: note: declared here
>      [[deprecated]] void A(string s, int i) {
>                          ^
> main.cpp:21:21: warning: 'void A(std::__cxx11::string, int)' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
>          A("Hello",42);
>                      ^
> main.cpp:13:25: note: declared here
>      [[deprecated]] void A(string s, int i) {
>                          ^
> ```

See an [online example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9da89c6b9fe25e3a) compiled with g++.

You can even decorate that with a message for your coworkers maintaining the code base:

```
   [[deprecated("Get rid of these performance killing calls."
                " Use A(A::getPrecomputedHash(s)) instead.")]] 
      void A(string s) {
      }
```